# How to get element id of a text which is in selected mode using selenium webdriver?

Tags: winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

There are multiple id's in website, but I want to get id of a text which is in selected mode using Selenium Webdriver.

From below code, how can i get only id which is "Colour" ?

```
<td>

<select id="Colour">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="ct">Red</option>
<option selected="selected" value="ctt">Blue</option>
</select>

</td>
```

Thank you

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: String gettingid = this.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Blue')]/option[@selected]")).GetAttribute("id");

Comment: The selected option `Blue` doesn't have any _id_ attribute.

Comment: no, it has only value attribute.

Comment: We need id of that section where the Blue is in selected mode. Please help me @DebanjanB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get `id` attribute with help of `selected` attribute for specific `td`. Please try below code

```
String requiredId = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@selected='selected']/..")).GetAttribute("id");
```

**Base on color name (not recommended as different color can be selected)**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//option[@selected='selected' and .='Blue']/..")));

    String requiredId = element.GetAttribute("id");
```

Comment: How can i pass string `getColour`   in place of Blue? @Muzzamil

Comment: Could you please share me the answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60023252/12826684)  @Muzzamil

Comment: @rajeshparipelly  try on that link.

Comment: Hi brother, Could you please share me this answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183880/how-to-wait-for-an-alert-in-selenium-webdriver-with-c) @Muzzamil

Comment: hi bro, could u plz help me solve this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060135/how-to-wait-until-a-dropdown-is-loaded-using-selenium-webdriver) @Muzzamil

Answer (score 0):

```
<i>
WebElement Cct; 
cct = driver.findElement(By.id("Colour");
String blue = blue.getAttribute("value");
Assert.assertEquals(value, "Blue");
</i>
```

Comment: We have hundreds of id's

Comment: You need to perform a click on this element or what?

Comment: i need all the id's, whenever the Blue is in select mode. @Old_the_jackal