# How to pass string to an XPath containing text?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I get id of a text which is in selected mode using Selenium Webdriver by using this code:

`String requiredId = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@selected='selected' and .='Blue']/..")).GetAttribute("id");`

How can i pass string `getColour`in place of Blue?

Thank you

Comment: $"/option[@selected='selected' and .='{getColour}']/.." should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a string this way. Try below code

```
    string getColourin = "Red";
    String requiredId = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@selected='selected' and .='" + getColourin +"']/..")).GetAttribute("id");
```

**OR**

**using string.Format**

```
string xpathBefore = "//option[@selected='selected' and .='{0}']/..";
string getColourin = "Red";
string finalXpath = string.Format(xpathBefore, getColourin);

String requiredId = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(finalXpath)).GetAttribute("id");
```

Comment: Hi brother, could you please share me this answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386916/how-to-increase-code-execution-time-limit-in-selenium-webdriver-using-c-sharp) @Muzzamil

Comment: @bydukaan  I hv answered long back. Please chk there

Comment: Hi bro, plz help me by solving this issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084609/how-to-wait-until-javascript-fully-loaded-in-a-div-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Bro, waiting for your help for above link @Muzzamil

Comment: Above Link is not clickable

Comment: Hi bro, Could you please solve this issue. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65999006/12826684) Thank you. @Muzzamil