# How to wait until <div> section reload using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium-webdriver

There are multiple dropdowns in div section. If i select an option in one of the dropdown, then all the other dropdowns loads autmatically without page reload. This is because of only that particular  section reloads. Sometimes this loads fast and sometimes slow.
How can we set webdriver to wait until this div section reload fully.

```
<div id="Fruits">
...
...
</div>
```

Am using C#
Thank you

Comment: Please add html code of div section how it looks after reload.

Comment: Try below code.

Comment: Some dropdowns selected option will changes.. No new lines were added in <div>

Comment: Ohh so we need html for dropdown after change. We need to wait for the change.

Comment: few days back, when we select an option from dropdown then page reloads and fetches the next dropdown list. For this, i used wait until element displayed functionality. But, that target website developer updated it to load only that selection.

Comment: as all the dropdowns in that <div> are javascript, i think we have to wait until all the javascript reloaded fully ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more of the HTML inside the `<div>` tag. This could give us enough information to answer your question. Please also include the C# code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

We can wait until `div` section  have any sub section or child node.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Fruits']//*"));
    });
```

Comment: bro, above code throwing this error: `OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@id='Fruits')]//* because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@id='Fruits')]//*' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Comment: same issue bro.

Comment: bro, are u available

Comment: This is looking same problem. You have to wait for the changed dropdown option after reload. You have that code already