# How to replace innerHTML code using Selenium Webdriver C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML CODE:

```
<select name="ddlFruit" id="ddlFruit" class="Searchddl">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="447">Grapes</option>
    <option value="448">Mango</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="449">Apple</option>
</select>
```

How can i replace

> selected="selected"

to other options using selenium webdriver.

Eg:

```
<select name="ddlFruit" id="ddlFruit" class="Searchddl">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="447">Grapes</option>
    <option value="448">Mango</option>
    <option value="449">Apple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute js script to modify attribute:

```
var webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
var webElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id('id'));
jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('selected','selected');",webElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option selected Property

The [selected](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_selected.asp) option property sets or returns the selected state of an option.

As per the HTML:

```
<select name="ddlFruit" id="ddlFruit" class="Searchddl">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="447">Grapes</option>
    <option value="448">Mango</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="449">Apple</option>
</select>
```

The option with text as **Apple** is selected.

---

### This usecase

The *`selected`* property can be replaced to other options only by selecting the other `<option>`.

To select the `<option>` with text as **Grapes** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451267/how-to-click-on-the-radio-button-through-the-element-id-attribute-using-selenium/62451578#62451578) and you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector* and `SelectByValue()`:

  ```
  new SelectElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("select.Searchddl#ddlFruit")))).SelectByValue("447");
  ```
- Using *XPath* and `SelectByText()`:

  ```
  new SelectElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("//select[@class='Searchddl' and @id='ddlFruit']")))).SelectByText("Grapes");
  ```

Comment: I dont want to click any element, Just i want to replace that source code at that moment. @DebanjanB

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("identifier")))
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("option")
```

where identifier is a way of finding the drop down, and option is the option to select.

Comment: I dont want to click any element, Just i want to replace that source code at that moment. @OctopuSS7

Comment: In that case, where `element` is the element you want, `element.InnerHTML = "What ever you want"`

Comment: ok, but how can i insert selected="selected" to Grapes and remove previous selected="selected"  @OctopusSS7

Comment: This is all on the selenium documentation now. Have a look there.