# How to Wait for an Alert in Selenium WebDriver with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can i set Selenium WebDriver to Wait for an Alert before accepting it instead of Thread.Sleep?

As website, sometimes loads very slowly or sometimes fast.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should apply webdriver wait for an  alert to be present properly.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
```

**OR write a boolean function to check alert present and use it for wait**

```
bool IsAlertShown(WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    } catch(NoAlertPresentException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Use it as below**

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(driver => IsAlertShown(driver));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207720/discussion-on-answer-by-muzzamil-how-to-wait-for-an-alert-in-selenium-webdriver).

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'WebDriverWait'

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
IWebElement element = wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")));
```

https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm

Comment: Thank you, for sharing the answer.. But, I want to wait the driver, till alert loads. As sometimes, page loads first and later the alert loads slowly. @Sergiy Matvienko