# How to wait until a dropdown is loaded using selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have 2 dropdown menus on a page.

> First dropdown:

```
<select name="ddlColor_N" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlColor_N\',\'\')', 0)" id="ddlColor_N" class="Searchddl" style="text-decoration: none; width: 152px; height: 22px;">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
        <option value="91_CC_A">Red</option>
        <option value="248_PS_A">Green</option>
        <option value="27_CG_A">Yellow</option>
    </select>
```

> Second dropdown

```
<select name="ddlFruit_N" id="ddlFruit_N" class="Searchddl" style="text-decoration: none; width: 152px; height: 22px;">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="447">Grapes</option>
<option value="448">Mango</option>
<option value="449">Apple</option>
</select>
```

When i click on Red in first dropdown, then in second dropdown Apple will be automatically loaded after couple of seconds.

Here comes my problem, that how can i wait for the second dropdown to load fully.

Am using C#
Thank you

Comment: Please add html code in question.

Comment: bro, plz check. Am using C# @Muzzamil

Comment: Check the answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code. We will check for options to load.

```
public static SelectElement FindSelectElementWhenPopulated(IWebDriver driver, By by, int delayInSeconds)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delayInSeconds));
        return wait.Until<SelectElement>(drv => 
        {
            SelectElement element = new SelectElement(drv.FindElement(by));
            if (element.Options.Count >= 2)
            {
                return element;
            }

            return null;
        }
        );
    }
```

and I call it like this:

```
Myclass.FindSelectElementWhenPopulated(driver, By.CssSelector("#ddlFruit_N"), 20);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218645/discussion-on-answer-by-muzzamil-how-to-wait-until-a-dropdown-is-loaded-using-se).